# How to write a string property value to JsonTextWriter with a TextWriter?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have C# class that can have content of various types, and an method that can write that content to a `TextWriter` in an efficient manner.  In certain cases, I have a collection of these objects that I write out as JSON array.  So, I have a `JsonTextWriter` which is set up appropriately.  It's in a state where I have called the methods to create the container `JObject`, `JArray` and `JObject`.  I've called `JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName()` and now comes this instance method.

```
public void WriteContentToValue(JsonTextWriter writer)
{
    if (this.Content is JToken) {
        (this.Content as JToken).WriteTo(writer);
    } else {
        using (StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter()) {
            WriteContentTo(swriter);
            writer.WriteValue(swriter.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

`WriteContentTo(swriter)` is a call to the method I mentioned earlier that takes a `TextWriter`.  I'm looking for a alternative to the code in the `else` block that doesn't involve creating a `StringWriter` instance and forcing creation of an intermediary string with `StringWriter.ToString()` in order to call `JsonTextWriter.WriteValue(string)`.

Comment: `JsonTextWriter.WriteValue` has an overload that takes an `object`.  Have you tried that? 
 i.e. `writer.WriteValue(Content)`?

Comment: @BrianRogers I need to be in control of how `Content` is converted to text; that's what `WriteContentTo(TextWriter)` is for.

Comment: Can you at least show us what `WriteContentTo()` does then?

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me, but it does something different if `Content` is `string`, `IList<string>`, `XElement`, `JToken` (obviously, not used when called from this method, but used for other callers), perhaps another type I've forgotten.  It converts and writes to `TextWriter` in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: What prevents you from implementing that same logic in `WriteContentToValue` except writing to `JsonTextWriter` instead of `TextWriter`?

Comment: The logic in `WriteContentTo` writes to a `TextWriter`, which has methods to write strings a piece at a time (using file buffers or whatever is appropriate for the concrete `TextWriter` class, possibly without creating an in-memory string).  Or, it could be passed to other compatible methods like a `JsonTextWriter` constructor.  The only equivalent option I've found to write a property value with `JsonTextWriter` is the `WriteValue(string)` method, for which I need to reduce everything to a `string` instance first, which is exactly what I've done in the question code.  I can't write piecemeal.

Comment: In that case, I think what you have already is the best you're going to be able to do.  `JsonTextWriter` doesn't provide a means to write a partial value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no deserialization happening in this that I can see.

```
JObject o = new JObject(
    new JProperty("Name", "John Smith"),
    new JProperty("BirthDate", new DateTime(1983, 3, 20))
    );

JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
Person p = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(o), typeof(Person));

Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
```

When using StringWriter be sure to be careful of your instances.

I would highly recommend looking into the documentation on this as well. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenWriter.htm

Comment: Deserialization has not thing to do with my question.  I have looked at documentation for `JsonSerializer` and `JTokenWriter`, and they don't help with the challenge I described, that I can see.  I have a `JProperty` that I want to give a `Value`, and I want to write that value without reducing it to a string first.  I see nothing of that in your answer, unfortunately.